# Asking for a name and returning the length of the name in C

Tags: c, counting

I've been struggling with this code for quite some time now.
This is my first time posting here.  I am new to C, and I feel that I almost got it.

I have to ask for your name, middle initial, and last name.  Then I greet you and tell you the length of your name.  Sounds simple enough.  I have the following code, I have to use the header file as it is  here and that makes things worse.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, I feel that I already applied all my knowledge to it and still can't get it to work.

This is my header file:

```
#ifndef NAME_H_
#define NAME_H_

struct name{
   char first[20];
   char middle;
   char last[20];
};

#endif
```

and this is my .c file:

```
#include "name.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define nl printf("\n");

int strlen(char*s);

char first;
char middle;
char last;

main()
{
    printf("enter your first name : ");
    scanf("%c", &first);
    printf("\n enter your middle initial name : ");
    scanf("%c", &middle);
    printf("\n enter your last name: ");
    scanf("%c", &last);

    printf("\n\n Hello %c",first, " %c" ,middle, " %c", last);
    printf("\n The String returned the following length: ",strlen);
}
```

I have t use `printf` and `scanf`, then store the name components a name "structure" imported from name.h and lastly use `int strlen(char *s);` to calculate it.

I get this output with the weird indentation and everything:

> enter your first name : Joe
>
> enter your middle initial name :
>   enter your last name:
>
> Hello J
>   The String returned the following length: [-my user id]$

Thanks!

Comment: The first character of your .c file is a .(dot), remove that and run again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things about this are not quite right.

First, you shouldn't be declaring `strlen` yourself.  It's a standard C library function, which means you should include the appropriate header.  In this case,

```
#include <string.h>
```

Second, you're storing the input in variables of type `char`.  Those are literally what they say: they store a single character.  So unless you're only allowing people to have single-character names, you need a bit more than that.  This sort of string input problem is actually rather tricky in C, since you have to do explicit memory management and don't know how much data the user is going to send you in advance.  One of the simpler things is to just use a large buffer and truncate, but for a more complex program you'd want to do error handling and possibly dynamically resize the buffer.  But for starters:

```
char first[1024];
char middle[1024];
char last[1024];
```

will at least get you started.  Your `struct name` has some of this, but you're not currently using it (and the sizes are pretty small).

Next, `scanf` is a tricky way to get input strings.  `scanf` of a `%s` pattern will happily read more than 1024 characters and write over the end of the buffer and destroy your program.  This is why C programmers usually read input data using `fgets` instead, since then you can more easily say how big of a buffer you're willing to read:

```
fgets(first, sizeof(first), stdin);
```

Be aware that if the user enters more than 1023 characters, it will read the first 1023 characters and then leave the rest there, where you'll end up reading it as part of the middle name.  String handling in C is complex!  C is not good at this sort of thing; that's why people tend to use Perl or similar languages for this sort of interactive string handling where you don't know sizes in advance.  In C, you have to pursue a strategy like repeatedly calling `fgets` until you get a newline at the end of the result and then deciding whether to dynamically resize your data structure or throw an error.  Alternately, you can use `scanf` with `%1023s` but you need to qualify the format to specify the maximum length.  The syntax is a bit weird and tricky; `fgets` is simpler when you're reading character strings.

As mentioned in the other answer, `strlen` is a function that you need to call on a `char *` variable (or `char` array) to get the length of the string it holds.  You probably want to call it on `first`, `middle`, and `last` and add them together.

Finally, in your last `printf`, you have to pass one format and then all of the arguments for that format. You want something more like:

```
printf("\n\n Hello %s %s %s", first, middle, last);
```

(once you fix the type of those variables).

This is a lot of random detail.  I hope it helps some.  The important brief takeaway is that a string in C is a sequence of `char` ending in a `char` with a value of 0, and all C data structures have to be sized in advance (either statically or dynamically with `malloc`).  C furthermore has no bounds checking, so it's completely up to you to ensure that you only read as much data as you created space for.

Comment: Thanks, it's looking healthier now.  The good thing is that it still runs.  The bad news is that it still runs wrong, but in a healthier way.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
strlen(first)
```

to get the length of variable first ..similarly for other varibles... To get the cumulative length use

```
printf("\n Length: ",strlen(first)+strlen(middle)+strlen(last));
```

Comment: That's because your name variables are currently declared as single characters instead of strings.